# Dynamically Adding items to an un-order list in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

if i create a html ul. and wanted to dynamically add list items to this list.

so i have :

```
<ul id="test" runat="server">
</ul>
```

is there a way i can add list item to this list dynamically in asp.net i am using vb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Repeater or a ListView to easily create a list of `<li>`.